# How to pass a parameter from an input element

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use an  input value as a parameter of my "doubleSize" function passing through onclick method.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script> 

function doubleSize(x)
{

        ....//some code

}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p> Give a number :
<input id="inpt" type="text"></p>
<button id="but" type="button" onclick="doubleSize('????')" >click me!</button>
<div><span id="result"></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Input itself or its value?

Comment: The value of the input.

Comment: Well, then @Shryme solution will do the trick. Just beware that value will be a string not a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to pass it like this:

```
onclick="doubleSize(document.getElementById('inpt').value)"
```

Comment: I thought that I needed something like `code`onclick="doubleSize(javascript:document.getElementById('inpt').value)"`code`

Comment: You don't need to specify javascript like this because it's already javascript inside the onclick, that's why you can do onclick="alert(1)" and an alert will pop.

Answer (score 0):

you must put the function in **head**  **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SNH4w/)**

```
<button id="but" type="button" onclick="doubleSize(document.getElementById('inpt').value)" >click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: Fiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/cUA9K/1/

```
<button id="but" type="button" onclick="doubleSize(document.getElementById('inpt').value)" >click me!</button>
```

Comment: Why do you add the same exact answer as mehdi who already wrote the same exact answer as me?

Comment: Because you didn't provide fiddle. Seems like you are new here. You can have more than one answer for same question, as long as you are adding more options and clarifying it more clearly. You should read FAQ section of stackoverflow. Oh and BTW, my answer was before his :P. Hence his answer is at the top. One who submit's late get's on the top.

Comment: Me: answered 15 mins ago, You: answered 10 mins ago it's at the top because it got accepted, and i don't find adding a fiddle to 1 line of code that usefull

Comment: It's useful, because sometimes OP can miss parts while copy pasting from what they are doing. Giving a visual thing of how it works is always helpful. And yes, to answer your point if you edit your answer it'll be on top, because then it becomes the most recent.